# How can I find out what's seeding in Vuze if it's not listed anywhere in the application?

Tags: linux, fedora, download, application, bittorrent

I use Vuze (formally known as Azuereus) for downloading torrents. But for some time now it's been seeding something that I can't see or find anywhere. It's not listed in any of the lists that are within the application, but the upload is showing 100% upload used(to the limit) but the upload in the lists are only a fraction of that.

[image]